# Wrong width and (x,y) position in Selenium when I employ HtmlUnitDriver

Tags: selenium

I am trying to use Selenium to open a URL in server-side and get the width and the position of the images inside that URl. This is the code that I am using:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    HtmlUnitDriver driver=new HtmlUnitDriver();

    driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
    Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(Level.OFF);

    String Url = "http://www.centennialwindows.com/";
    driver.get(Url);
    List<WebElement> resultsDiv = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//img"));

    System.out.println(resultsDiv.size());
    for (int i=0; i<resultsDiv.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(i+1 + ". " + resultsDiv.get(i).getText());
        System.out.println(resultsDiv.get(i).getAttribute("src"));
        System.out.println(resultsDiv.get(i).getAttribute("width"));
        System.out.println(resultsDiv.get(i).getLocation());

    }
}
```

When I am using `WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();` it opens the firefox and it sends me correct results. Because I don't want to use firefox or any other browser to be opened, I tried to use `HtmlUnitDriver()` but it sends me null for width and (5,5) for the position of all images. How can I solve this?

Comment: This [link](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/HtmlUnitDriver) might help you understand why HtmlUnitDriver is effective for faster feedback but is not always efficient.
Also, go through [this](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/8323) too for better understanding and it suggests an alternative too.

Comment: @Subh Thanks! I ended up with Phanbedder which is a pre-build package for PhantomJS with its dependencies. It works prefect in java on my Mac but I could not integrate it with Spring yet. There is no exception but nothing works after `driver = new PhantomJSDriver(dcaps)`. Have you done this before?

Comment: I am afraid that's the extent of my knowledge. I am aquainted with automation in browser only. Headless browser automation, not done yet.. I hope somebody else helps you out.. :)